# What is the implication if the Kretschmann scalar for two metrics are same?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

Does it mean that they are describing the same spacetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implication. It doesn't mean that they are describing the same spacetime. The Riemann tensor has 20 independent components, so knowing one quadratic scalar combination of them isn’t much of a constraint on the geometry.

In general, even a *complete* set of invariants is insufficient to determine the metric. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_invariant_(general_relativity)#Distinguishing_Lorentzian_manifolds).